# numpy.core.multiarray failed to import while invoking python module through C++ application developed in xcode

Tags: python, c++, numpy, anaconda, virtualenv

I am using anaconda to maintain python virtual environment. I have a python module which i want to invoke from c++ application developed through xcode 9.2.

`pModule = PyImport_Import(pName)` fails in c++ application with error

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import.
```

`pName` here refers to a module `xyz.py`. xyz's `__init__.py` imports cv2 which in turn is using `from .cv2 import *`. This fails with error "numpy.core.multiarray failed to import". Packages for opencv and numpy is installed in same virtual environment still its not able to import numpy's core.multiarray module.

To me this doesn't seems to be a path issue, as I am using PySys_SetPath to set path where packages are installed , path looks like `anaconda/envs/XYZ/lib/python3.5/site-packages`.

Just to add more info, xyz module i am using is for object detection, to be more specific its imageAI object detection module. So under python3.5/site-packages I have imageai's Detection module ( python3.5/site-packages/imageai/Detection/). In Detection there is **init**.py which is trying to import cv2. The error received is when cv2 trying to import numpy.core.multiarray, both cv2 and numpy exists in path python3.5/site-packages.

Answer (score 0):

What work it to reinstall numpy using conda NOT pip

```
pip uninstall numpy
conda install numpy
```

Comment: Tom, Thanks for replying. I tried it but it didn't help. I tried an alternative approach that fixed this. In XYZ's __init__.py I added "import numpy.core.multiarray", before cv2 is imported, that has fixed the issue. Still wondering how that worked.